# How to select multiple rows in ng2-smart-table component with checkbox?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table

I am using **ng2-smart-table** from
https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation

***Live Demo:***
http://akveo.com/ngx-admin/pages/tables/smart-table

**Please help me with below questions:**

1. I want to select multiple rows and call one function so where I need to write this code in ng2-smart-table?
2. Can I select multiple rows and call one function on selected rows ?

***I have written below code in .ts and .html files:***

**smart-table-component.ts:**

```
 actions: {
      add: false,
      edit: true,
      delete: false,
      custom: [{ name: 'ourCustomAction'}],
      position: 'left',
      columnTitle: 'Actions'

    },   

    mode: 'external',
```

**smart-table-component.html**:

```
   <nb-card-body>
    <ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" allowFiltering='true' allowPaging='true' [source]="windchillData"
     (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)" (custom)="onCustomAction($event)" (edit)="onEdit($event)">
    </ng2-smart-table>
  </nb-card-body>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**1- I want to select multiple rows and call one function so where I need to write this code in ng2-smart-table?**

**Answer:**

For selecting multiple rows in `ng2-smart-table`, you need to add configuration in your `settings` Object.

**Example:**

```
settings = {
    // This `selectMode` is the configuration for selecting multiple rows in the table using checkbox
    selectMode: 'multi',
    delete: {
      confirmDelete: true,

      deleteButtonContent: 'Delete data',
      saveButtonContent: 'save',
      cancelButtonContent: 'cancel'
    },
    add: {
      confirmCreate: true,
    },
    edit: {
      confirmSave: true,
    },
    columns: {
      // columns configuration
    },
  };
```

**2- Can I select multiple rows and call one function on selected rows ?**

`ng2-smart-table` have an event to get `userSelectedRows`, we can use that event to get all the selected rows and then call a function to do something with all selected rows.

**Example:**

- **Step1: Add event handler in the template**

```html
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" allowFiltering='true' allowPaging='true' [source]="windchillData" (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)" (custom)="onCustomAction($event)" (edit)="onEdit($event)" (userRowSelect)="onUserRowSelect($event)"></ng2-smart-table>
```

- **Step2: Create event handler in `component.ts` to get the selected rows**

```js
onUserRowSelect(event) {
    this.selectedRows = event.selected;
}
```

- **Step3: Create button and call a function to do something with selected rows**

Button in `html`

```html
<button (click)="onClick()"> Get Selected </button>
```

Click handler in `component.ts`

```js
onClick() {
    // It will console all the selected rows
    console.log(this.selectedRows);
  }
```

Here you can see this in working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-ng2-smart-table-18qsws

Comment: when you add multi selectmode, you lose the ability to call row by click on row itself, it only gets called by clicking the checkbox

Comment: @AbhijeetKhangarot that's the issue I'm facing right now !

Answer (score 5):

I am not too familiar with this library but following should help:

**html**

```
<button (click)="logAllSelectedRows()">log All selected</button>
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="source" (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)" (rowSelect)="rowSelectedHandler($event)">
```

**ts**

```
  selectedRows = [];
  rowSelectedHandler(rowData:{isSelected:boolean, data:any}){
    if(rowData.isSelected === false){
      /*remove row*/
      this.selectedRows = this.selectedRows.filter((rowItem)=>rowItem .id !== rowData.data.id)
    }else {
      /*add row*/
      this.selectedRows = [...this.selectedRows, ...rowData.data];
      console.log('added rowdata');
    }
  }

  logAllSelectedRows(){
      console.log(this.selectedRows);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

In your ng2-smart-table **settings** (`[settings]="settings"`), add this line to enable selecting more than one row:

```
selectMode: 'multi',
```

Then, in your **template**, add the (userRowSelect) event to your ng2-smart-table:

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" allowFiltering='true' allowPaging='true' [source]="windchillData" (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)" (custom)="onCustomAction($event)" (edit)="onEdit($event)" (userRowSelect)="onUserRowSelect($event)"></ng2-smart-table>
```

In your **component**, update the list of selected rows at every (userRowSelect):

```
private selectedRows: any;

// ...

onUserRowSelect(event) {
    this.selectedRows = event.selected;
}
```

Still in the component, add a function that does what you want with the selected rows:

```
public doSomething() {
    // Do something with `this.selectedRows`
}
```

Add a button, and call your function when it is clicked!

```
<button (click)="doSomething()"> Run code on selected rows! </button>
```